# Lock screen is crashing the UI in 20.04 after an update

Tags: gnome, 20.04, lock-screen

I've been running Ubuntu 20.04 for about a month now and I still don't really know my way around so I'm not sure how to go about addressing this.

I did an update with apt update and I'm guessing there was something related to the UI(Gnome?) in there. Now when I hit Win+L or lock from the dock menu the screen flashes purple and my active window changes for a second before returning to how it was. I'm guessing the UI is crashing but I'm not sure what to do about it. Any suggestions? Is there any logs I can access to help identify the issue?

Update:
The problem seems to come from the Dash to panel extension. Turning the extension on and off again in tweaks fixes the issue for a while.

Comment: "I have the same issue" - sure this does not help but I am also on Ubuntu 20.04 with an AMD RX 5700XT. Trying to lock the screen *sometimes* works, other times it just crashes gnome and you are back at your normal screen.

Comment: I've found the problem is caused by the Dash to panel extension I'm using. Turning the extension on and off again in tweaks temporarily fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue.
It's a bug between Gnome-shell 3.36.2 and the extension Dash to panel.

Solution 1 : turn off dash to panel and wait for Gnome shell 3.36.3

Solution 2 : activate focal-proposed, and install Gnome-shell 3.36.3 (with Synaptic for example, in order to install easily  only gnome-shell)

Comment: Bug is also in gnome 3.36.8